# Get distinct, specific element from mongo document array in a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below given are my 4 documents with exact structure in mongo collection, I have such 276 documents in my collection. I simply want to get the distinct "Campaign Names" from my collection.

Values and Header arrays are one to one mapped:

```
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId("58a4adb4ef2bf41444c79e5b1"),
    "Status" : false,
    "Headers" : [ 
        "Campaign Name", 
        "Ad Set Name", 
        "Ad Name", 
        "URL Tags", 
    ],
    "Values" : [ 
        "Campaign 1", 
        "Adset 1", 
        "Ad 1", 
        "url tag1" 
    ]
}

,
{
        "_id" : "ObjectId("58a4adb4ef2bf41444c79e5b2"),
        "Status" : false,
        "Headers" : [ 
            "Campaign Name", 
            "Ad Set Name", 
            "Ad Name", 
            "URL Tags", 
        ],
        "Values" : [ 
            "Campaign 2", 
            "Adset 2", 
            "Ad 2", 
            "url tag 2" 
        ]
    },
{
        "_id" : "ObjectId("58a4adb4ef2bf41444c79e5b3"),
        "Status" : false,
        "Headers" : [ 
            "Campaign Name", 
            "Ad Set Name", 
            "Ad Name", 
            "URL Tags", 
        ],
        "Values" : [ 
            "Campaign 2", 
            "Adset 2", 
            "Ad 2", 
            "url tag 2" 
        ]
    },
{
        "_id" : "ObjectId("58a4adb4ef2bf41444c79e5b4"),
        "Status" : false,
        "Headers" : [ 
            "Campaign Name", 
            "Ad Set Name", 
            "Ad Name", 
            "URL Tags", 
        ],
        "Values" : [ 
            "Campaign 4", 
            "Adset 4", 
            "Ad 4", 
            "url tag 4" 
        ]
    }
```

Needed Output:

```
Campaign 1,Campaign 2,Campaign 4
```

As Campaign 2 is reaping twice, so i want it to appear one time only as mentioned above.

Please help!!

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: Expected output would be first element of Values array from each document in my collection but they should be distinct. Don't want duplication.
It could be in any form, i don't want any specific format, i just want my required data.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to provide that information

Comment: sure doing it in a minute.

Comment: Why not try ? `db.collection.distinct("Values.0")`. Assuming you always take care of inserting data  at the right position in both `Headers` and `Values`.

Comment: Thanks veeram, this is awesome, you made my day, i am taking care of that. Why not putting it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done fairly simple with [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/):

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.Headers.length; i++) {
            if (this.Headers[i] === "Campaign Name" && i in this.Values) {
                emit(this.Values[i], 1);
            }
        }
    },
    function(header, values) {
            return 1
    },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
)
```

Comment: Thanks alex, it looks logical to me, but its giving me
Error: map reduce failed:{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
 "code" : 10075,
 "codeName" : "Location10075"
}
Sorry i am new to mongo.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It seemed to be too simple to test =). I have updated the answer. You are basically interested in the unique _id in the reduced array.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Its awesome.

Answer (score 3):

This answer depends on fixed index for the value you are looking for in all documents.

So assuming you always take care of inserting data at the right position in both `Headers` and `Values`.

For `Campaign Name` the index is 0 in `Values` array

You can get away with below query

```
db.collection.distinct("Values.0").
```

Comment: If the index of Campaign Name is not fixed, but dynamic, so map reduce is the only way to do it?

Comment: may be. just out of curiosity is updating your structure an option for you ?

Comment: Yes, i am planning to change it... can you give me some good suggestions?

Comment: You can start with merging the header and value into a document. Something like `"HeadersAndValues" : [ 
            {"header":"Campaign Name", value:"Campaign 4"},
            {"header":"Ad Set Name", value:"Adset 4"} 
           ....
        ]` and then you can use aggregation to do distinct value calculation.

Comment: That's good idea. I will definitely do it. I went through an example like that in mongo official documentation. I will surely implement it. Thanks for taking out a lot of time for my issue and for such an awesome advice too.